# "window.open _self" issue works only on IE7 or less

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a very very old application developed in ASP.
It works fine if I run it on Internet Explorer legacy mode (emulation of IE7).

The latest Win10 update changed something on Internet Explorer, so my application has some problems.

I need a solution to make this application run on Chrome or Firefox or Edge... just to get rid of IE!

**Details**
I have a page made of several iframes with a button to add a sub page. Once I click on that, I expect to see the iframe reloaded and updated. It worked fine... of course!
The guilty line is the following

```
<button onclick="window.open('add_new_sub.asp?grp=xxx;sid=yyy','_self');">...</button>
```

The problem is related to the "_self" params. Removing it the code works opening another page instead of updating the current iframe.

Why in your opinion?

What's wrong in a code that open a page inside ad iframe and get back to it?

Thanks

Comment: Try just removing `window.open()` entirely.  If you are trying to redirect the current frame/window to a new page, then you can probably just do `document.location = 'add_new_sub.asp?...`.

Comment: Also, do you even need JavaScript here at all?  Could you change this to a `<a href="add_new_sub.asp?...">...</a>`?

Comment: You should no longer be using `window.open()`, but understanding your pain with legacy junk, and just wanting to get it to work before a major refactoring effort, do this: 1. Set a `name` attribute on your `<iframe>` tag. 2. Replace `_blank` in the `target` of the `window.open()` with the name of that `iframe`.

Comment: you can try like `<a target="Iframe_name" href="https://Site_URL">link1</a>` or you can try to set `Iframe.src` in the function by calling it on button click.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'll test your first solution, but the second one does not fit my needs at all.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, your solution seems interesting, I'll test it for sure!

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT also your solution deserves a test.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.location.href = ‘your_new_url’